# Skipping misspelled words in Luis utterances

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am working on a Azure BOT service, where it has to take some words like GGID as a utterance and give me reply, but the spell checker taking it to auto correct and serving GOD in place of GGID, How can I get out of this issue?

Comment: Before passing to Azure spell checker check with a conditional if the utterance  contains `GGID`. I have done same thing while using language analysis service and LUIS. Let me know if you need example as well how to skip that, for getting the Idea.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, there are utterances for GGID,  and also having confidence score of 95, but because of spell check, it is taking as GOD. Please help me with how to skip that. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: I understand, you are checking that on spell API by passing into that right? So in that part just it to LUIS directly without having passed to spell check API. include your code on your question to investigate it other then it would be tough to add answer.

Comment: sorry to ask this, but can you please be clear?

Comment: Clear about what? Include your code snippet on your question.

Comment: dict.Add("Luis_spellChecker", data);
            string url = config["spellCheckUrl"] +data;

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", config["spellCheckKey"]);

Comment: Are you using bing spell checker and LUIS right which are two different API, so my point is while are you checking for spelling if it  contains `GGID` then don't pass in  to spell check API, directly pass to LUIS.

Comment: can you let me know, how to do that?

Comment: Unless he is configuring that in the LUIS connector. In that case it might be better to create two recognizers, one with spell check and one without. It might be more streamlined to call the APIs separately, but this would be an option to minimize code changes if the setting is already being made within the recognizer setup.

Comment: will adding Phrase list helps, in this case?